# Clojure closure not behaving as expected?

Tags: clojure

The repl returns 2 when expected to return 5.

```
(defn counter [] 
  (let [count 1]
    (fn [] 
      (+ count 1)
    )
  )
)

(defn test-counter []
  (let [increment (counter)]
    (increment)
    (increment)
    (increment)
    (increment)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count` is not a mutable variable so `(+ count 1)` does not change its value. If you want mutation you can store the count in an `atom` and update it using `swap!`:

```
(defn counter []
  (let [count (atom 0)]
    (fn [] (swap! count inc))))
```